# How can I log date and datetime as strings with structlog?

Tags: python, datetime, structlog

Structlog seems to use `__repr__` when creating log messages, which leads to `date` and `datetime` objects looking like `'datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 20, 10, 1, 52, 414750)'` where `'2018-09-20 10:01:52.414750'` would be preferable.

I would have thought there would be an off the shelf processor to handle this, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with, but I'm concerned about the performance given the highly recursive nature of it, and the unnecessary rebuilding of `list` and `dict` objects.

```
def _convert_dates(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
        # all datetimes are also dates
        return str(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        # Assume dates won't be keys
        return {k: _convert_dates(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [_convert_dates(v) for v in obj]
    return obj


def dates_to_str_filter(_, __, event):
    return _convert_dates(event)
```

Then include `dates_to_str_filter` in `processors` for the `structlog.configure` call.